# creating cart promotion rule in Magento but this is not applying on subtotal

Tags: magento-1.9, cart-rule

I am creating a Magento cart promotion rule but this is not working as we are thinking. I have two products in cart and apply this promo code but this is applying on first product amount only not all product subtotal.

link. 
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=AD49CC6A701028A5!123&authkey=!AHrXZMlIvEsEQIw&ithint=folder%2cpng

Comment: Pradeep, were you able to solve this issue? Please do share

Answer (score 0):

Do you have **other promotional rules**? If so, try disabling and see if it works. If there are other rules, it may be happening any conflict between them.